# Python Binary Search item won't equal target

Tags: python

I am trying to make a binary search algorithm but I can't get it to work. It eventually reaches the target number but it won't count it as equal to the target. 
I.E. if 78 was the target number eventually array[midpoint] does equal 78 but my if statement doesn't see it that way it will see it as more or less than 78.

```
[3, 30, 33, 38, 57, 61, 70, 89, 93, 98]
Enter a number to search for.93
5
61
more
8
93
more
9
98
more
10
```

this was the result of one test. I made it print more just to know what it was doing. The first number it prints is the mid point and the second is the item in the array at that point.

After it reaches 10 I get an index out of range error.

Here is my code.

```
def BinarySearch(array):
    found = False
    startpos = 0
    endpos = len(array)
    mid = 0
    target = raw_input("Enter a number to search for.")

    while found == False or startpos <= endpos:
        mid = (startpos + endpos)/2


        if array[mid] == target:
            print "Found"
            found = True
            return found
        elif array[mid] < target:
            startpos = mid + 1

        else :
            endpos = mid - 1


    return found
```

Comment: `93 == "93"` returns `False`.

Comment: I guess this is a nice learning exercise, but there's a standard Python [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module. BTW, it's better design to get user input in the outer part of your program, and then pass the input (after its been converted, and possibly validated) to your inner functions that do the actual work. It's ok for a small program like this, but it gets terribly messy in larger programs.

Comment: I had that in my initial version but that didn't get close to working, the exercises pseudocode had it this way so I decided to just follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` is a string.  You need to convert it to an integer. `target = int(target)`

Answer (score 1):

- The initial value of `endpos` should be `len(array) - 1`, as the index of array starts from 0.
- Replace `or` with `and`, as any one of these two conditions can terminate the `while` loop.
- Convert `target` value to `int`, that is `target = int(target)`

Comment: Why considering changing `or` to `and` where the `return found` will break the loop anyway? Better getting rid of it and only use `while startpos <= endpos`, `return True` inside the loop and `return False` at the end.

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger, yes. I just correct the author's original mistake. not optimise the algorithm

Comment: It is not about optimization, it is about quality of code (and thus quality of answers). Optimization would be to `def search(array): target = int(raw_input("Enter a number to search for ")); return target in array`